# Get image from excel list of links

Tags: excel

I have an excel list of over 2000 apps for which I have been asked to make icons. The list has 3 columns: `Timestamp` (when requested), `App Name`, and the `Play Link` to the app. The script must follow the link, grab the link to the App Icon, change w96 to w512, and then download that image.

Even if it is possible to do part of the work with a script, that would be helpful, but I don't even know where to start. Does anyone have any information on where to start, or even whether it's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest using [python](/questions/tagged/python), including the modules [openpyxl](/questions/tagged/openpyxl) for parsing the Excel, and [mechanize](/questions/tagged/mechanize) for retrieving the image.